# Como concatenar un variable una expresión jquery?

Tags: jquery

Saludos por favor si me pudieran ayudar con este problema que tengo, lo que sucede es que quiero poner una variable en esta sección de jquery  en donde esta #opcion quiero que salga por ejemplo :`#opcion0` siendo 0 la variable que en el ejemplo esta como cad , y cuando cambie la variable salga `#opcion1`

```
 $( "#opcion"+cad ).on('change',function(){}
```

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar seria genial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien, la situación es:

1. Existen varios elementos con ids opcion0, opcion1, opcion2,...
2. Quieres poder hacer referencia a opcionN utilizando `$("#opcion" + cad)` donde la variable cad contiene el valor N.

Si es así, entonces lo que tienes funciona perfectamente, lo único es que no cerraste adecuadamente el `on`. En otras palabras, tu implementación es correcta, es solo un problema de sintaxis. Intenta lo siguiente y todo debe salir bien.

```
$("#opcion"+cad).on('change',function() {
    console.log("cambiaste " + this.id);
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me fue de mucha ayuda